# How to end if statement in php

Tags: php, if-statement

The question is pretty much self-explanatory, I am having trouble how to end if statement in php.

For example,

```
<?php
if (argument) {
// end if statement
}
else if (different argument) {
// end if statement
}
else if (another different argument) {
// end if statement
}
else {
// do something
}
?>
```

Comment: Take out the else or do something, you've answered your own question...

Comment: For example, if the first if statement becomes true, I want the if statement not to read the entire if statement.

Comment: It won't it will exit

Comment: @Timeout Your edit completely changed the code snippet from the OP, and *invalidated an answer below* without warning. Since they are clearly asking for debugging help, this kind of thing should be *first clarified in the comments*, and allowing the OP to edit their own post, instead of blindly fixing.

Comment: @CrisToby Is the missing close brace actually a bad copy-paste, or is it the source of your worries?

Comment: @Ic. Yea,, sorry, I have edited it now.

Comment: I don't know what's real anymore now days... Going to bed.

Comment: @Codexer Everything is a figment of your imagination. Including this comment. :-P

Comment: Ok so let's get this straight for the record: With the curly brace there, the code does not do what you want. Right? (And what is it exactly you want it to do that it is not doing?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider carefully how an `if` condition works:

```
If (boolean condition) Then
    (consequent)
Else
    (alternative)
End If
```

> When an interpreter finds an `If`, it expects a boolean condition ...
>   and evaluates that condition. If the condition is `true`, the statements
>   following the `then` are executed. Otherwise, the execution continues
>   ... After either branch has been executed, control returns to the
>   point after the `end If`.

The `if` statement will end if none of its conditions evaluate to `true` or if one of its conditions evaluate to `true`. The statement(s) associated with the first `true` condition will evaluate, and the `if` statement will end.

See [Wikipedia's If–then(–else)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_(computer_programming)#If.E2.80.93then.28.E2.80.93else.29) for more.

Answer (score 1):

There should not be a closing brace on line 4, but there should be one at the end of all conditional statements.
The syntax is:

```
if (condition) 
  {
code to be executed if this condition is true;
} elseif (condition) 
  {
   code to be executed if this condition is true;
} else  
  {
code to be executed if all conditions are false;
 }
```

Further reference at:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_if_else.asp

Answer (score 0):

Change :

```
<?php
    if (argument) {
        // end if statement
    }
    else if (different argument) {
        // end if statement
    }
    else if (another different argument) {
        // end if statement
    else {
        // do something
    }
?>
```

To :

```
<?php
    if (argument) {
        // end if statement
    }
    else if (different argument) {
        // end if statement
    }
    else if (another different argument) {
        // end if statement
    }
    else {
        // do something
    }
?>
```

To use if statement, use the following syntax :

```
if (condition) {
    // Put your codes here
}
```

Another example, if you use else if :

```
else if (condition) {
    // Put your codes here
}
```

Use the curly bracket { } to contain your codes
PS: you just missed a } at the third if in your codes :)

Comment: @Codexer Ouch... Yes he did miss a bracket, and Timeout actually edited it out!! Undoing my downvote.

Comment: @Codexer Right? And what's worse is now it's back again and this time the OP put it there. :(

Comment: Why downvoting? 
(Codexer)[http://stackoverflow.com/users/1797425/codexer], the other answer states the same thing that he did miss a closing bracket, you need to pay attention! He has edited the mistake :(

Comment: sorry, I mean not you, but someone :(